# How to restrict some websites in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet

I would like to restrict some websites to be surfed. I mean I want to prevent access to some websites. Please guide me on how to do the same in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way, which works system-wide, is to set up entries in `/etc/hosts`

For example, add the following lines to the end of `/etc/hosts`, one for each site you want to block:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
127.0.0.1 example.net
127.0.0.1 www.example.net
```

This tells the system's DNS resolver *"please override the name to IP resolution for these host names"* and since it overrides it to `127.0.0.1`, those sites won't work.

Note that it is possible for users to circumvent this by using an HTTP proxy in the browser or if they were somehow to use an alternative DNS resolver, or if the site accept connections based on IP address only, and so on.

Comment: This is pretty much simple and explain it very well. Further, I'd prefer if you can add `sudo nano /etc/hosts` or `sudo vi /etc/hosts` to your answer. This may come in handy in future if any newbie users or similarly looking for an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal, and type `sudo vi /etc/hosts`.

Type `Shift+G`, then `Shift+A`, then `I`.

You should now see `--INSERT--` at the bottom of the screen. Then, cut and paste this code:

```
127.0.0.1 siteyouwanttoblock.com
```

To save, press `:` and type `wq` and click enter.

It's as simple as that!

Note: I have NOT come up with this answer. I just made it more simple for the newbies. All credits go to you, @neon_overload.

Comment: A good explanation like this is always needed.

Answer (score 2):

Best way for blocking and allowing sites

Url Blocking :

### your website ip and press tab type your ur website

go to Terminal  and type `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`

```
xxx.xx.x.x   yourwebsite.com  
175.XXX.xxx.xx  yourwebsite.com
202.XX.xx.xx  yourwebsite.com
```

### deny all sites (`*.*.*.*`) means all IPs

Open `sudo gedit /etc/hosts.deny` and add  `*.*.*.*`  in last line

### allow host ips(url ips). Find your URL IPs with `nslookup cmd` command

open `sudo gedit /etc/hosts.allow`

```
175.xxx.xxx.xx
175.1.xxx.xx
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
```

Open `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and type `#` before `servername 127.0.0.1` and add

```
servername 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This could be much, much clearer with a little thought. As it is I don't even want to try it because of the ambiguity.